# VS 2013 Express and Attach to Process

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013 Express Edition.

I'm trying to add Attach to Process for Debugging a program that is hosted in IIS. But I'm not able to find *Attach to Process*.

My question is, does vs 2013 Express edition have that functionality? Because I found the same `Attach to Process` in Premium edition.

Comment: For your info, I'm using vs 2013 Express for web. I have tried it with Administrator too. Even though i cannot find..!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Attach to Process` is supported by Express-Edition of Visual Studio 2013. I´m using "Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop" to debug Windows Services.

It can be found under "Debug->Attach to Process". Maybe you need to start Visual Studio as "Administrator"

To attach to IIS and its workers (w3wp.exe) it is required to check the CheckBox "Show processes from all users" at the bottom of the dialog. IIS and its workers use another account for execution than the account you start Visual Studio.

Comment: For your info, I'm using vs 2013 Express for web. I have tried it with Administrator too. Even though i cannot find..!